# Filesystem has been set read-only for clusters badly computed error

Tags: linux, filesystems, fat32

my sd cart run a long time in embed linux system,but sometime the filesystem set readonly and print bellow msg:
clusters badly computed (587 != 531)
FAT: Filesystem panic (dev hda6)

## i see source code from linux kernel as show this: who can explain why this error,tks very much.

/*
 * fat_chain_add() adds a new cluster to the chain of clusters represented
 * by inode.
 */

```
int fat_chain_add(struct inode *inode, int new_dclus, int nr_cluster)
{
    struct super_block *sb = inode->i_sb;
    struct msdos_sb_info *sbi = MSDOS_SB(sb);
    int ret, new_fclus, last;

    /*
     * We must locate the last cluster of the file to add this new
     * one (new_dclus) to the end of the link list (the FAT).
     */
    last = new_fclus = 0;
    if (MSDOS_I(inode)->i_start) {
        int fclus, dclus;

        ret = fat_get_cluster(inode, FAT_ENT_EOF, &fclus, &dclus);
        if (ret < 0)
            return ret;
        new_fclus = fclus + 1;
        last = dclus;
    }

    /* add new one to the last of the cluster chain */
    if (last) {
        struct fat_entry fatent;

        fatent_init(&fatent);
        ret = fat_ent_read(inode, &fatent, last);
        if (ret >= 0) {
            int wait = inode_needs_sync(inode);
            ret = fat_ent_write(inode, &fatent, new_dclus, wait);
            fatent_brelse(&fatent);
        }
        if (ret < 0)
            return ret;
        /*
         * FIXME:Although we can add this cache, fat_cache_add() is
         * assuming to be called after linear search with fat_cache_id.
         */
//      fat_cache_add(inode, new_fclus, new_dclus);
    } else {
        MSDOS_I(inode)->i_start = new_dclus;
        MSDOS_I(inode)->i_logstart = new_dclus;
        /*
         * Since generic_write_sync() synchronizes regular files later,
         * we sync here only directories.
         */
        if (S_ISDIR(inode->i_mode) && IS_DIRSYNC(inode)) {
            ret = fat_sync_inode(inode);
            if (ret)
                return ret;
        } else
            mark_inode_dirty(inode);
    }
    if (new_fclus != (inode->i_blocks >> (sbi->cluster_bits - 9))) {
        fat_fs_error(sb, "clusters badly computed (%d != %llu)",
                 new_fclus,
                 (llu)(inode->i_blocks >> (sbi->cluster_bits - 9)));
        fat_cache_inval_inode(inode);
    }
    inode->i_blocks += nr_cluster << (sbi->cluster_bits - 9);

    return 0;
}
```